# Xtext refering to element from different file does not work

Tags: dsl, xtext

Hello I am having two files in my xtext editor, the first one containing all definitions and the second one containing the executed recipe. The Grammar looks like this:

```
ServiceAutomationProgram:
    ('package' name=QualifiedName ';')?
    imports+=ServiceAutomationImport*
    definitions+=Definition*;

ServiceAutomationImport:
    'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard ';';

Definition:
    'define' ( TypeDefinition | ServiceDefinition |
    SubRecipeDefinition | RecipeDefinition) ';';

TypeDefinition:
        'quantity' name=ID  ;

SubRecipeDefinition:
    'subrecipe' name=ID '('( subRecipeParameters+=ServiceParameterDefinition (','
    subRecipeParameters+=ServiceParameterDefinition)*)? ')' '{'
    recipeSteps+=RecipeStep*
    '}';

RecipeDefinition:
    'recipe' name=ID '{' recipeSteps+=RecipeStep* '}';

RecipeStep:
    (ServiceInvocation | SubRecipeInvocation) ';';

SubRecipeInvocation:
    name=ID 'subrecipe' calledSubrecipe=[SubRecipeDefinition] '('(  parameters+=ServiceInvocationParameter (',' parameters+=ServiceInvocationParameter)*  )?')'
;

ServiceInvocation:
    name=ID 'service'  service=[ServiceDefinition] 
    '(' (parameters+=ServiceInvocationParameter (',' parameters+=ServiceInvocationParameter)*)? ')'
;

ServiceInvocationParameter:
    ServiceEngineeringQuantityParameter  | SubRecipeParameter
;

ServiceEngineeringQuantityParameter:
    parameterName=[ServiceParameterDefinition] value=Amount;
    


ServiceDefinition:
    'service' name=ID ('inputs' serviceInputs+=ServiceParameterDefinition (','
    serviceInputs+=ServiceParameterDefinition)*)?;

ServiceParameterDefinition:
    name=ID ':' (parameterType=[TypeDefinition]);


;

SubRecipeParameter:
    parameterName=[ServiceParameterDefinition]
;
QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
    QualifiedName '.*'?;

QualifiedName:
    ID ('.' ID)*;

Amount:
    INT ;
....
```

definitionfile file.mydsl:

```
define quantity Temperature;

define service Heater inputs SetTemperature:Temperature;

define subrecipe sub_recursive() {             
    Heating1 service Heater(SetTemperature 10); 
};
....
```

recipefile secondsfile.mydsl:

```
define recipe Main {                                 
                           
        sub1 subrecipe  sub_recursive(); 
};
        
.....
```

In my generator file which looks like this:

```
override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
        
        for (e : resource.allContents. toIterable.filter (RecipeDefinition)){     
            e.class;//just for demonstration add breakpoint here and //traverse down the tree
         }
         
    }
```

I need as an example the information RecipeDefinition.recipesteps.subrecipeinvocation.calledsubrecipe.recipesteps.serviceinvocation.service.name which is not accessible (null) So  some of the very deep buried information gets lost (maybe due to lazylinking?).
To make the project executable also add to the scopeprovider:

```
public IScope getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (context instanceof ServiceInvocationParameter
            && reference == MyDslPackage.Literals.SERVICE_INVOCATION_PARAMETER__PARAMETER_NAME) {

        ServiceInvocationParameter invocationParameter = (ServiceInvocationParameter) context;
        List<ServiceParameterDefinition> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if(invocationParameter.eContainer() instanceof ServiceInvocation) {
            ServiceInvocation serviceCall = (ServiceInvocation) invocationParameter.eContainer();
            ServiceDefinition calledService = serviceCall.getService();
            candidates.addAll(calledService.getServiceInputs());
            if(serviceCall.eContainer() instanceof SubRecipeDefinition) {
                SubRecipeDefinition subRecipeCall=(SubRecipeDefinition) serviceCall.eContainer();
                candidates.addAll(subRecipeCall.getSubRecipeParameters());
            }
            
            return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);
        }
        else if(invocationParameter.eContainer() instanceof SubRecipeInvocation) {
            SubRecipeInvocation serviceCall = (SubRecipeInvocation) invocationParameter.eContainer();
            SubRecipeDefinition calledSub = serviceCall.getCalledSubrecipe();
            candidates.addAll(calledSub.getSubRecipeParameters());
            return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);
        }
        
    
    }return super.getScope(context, reference);
}
```

When I put all in the same file it works as it does the first time executed after launching runtime but afterwards(when dogenerate is triggered via editor  saving) some information is missing. Any idea how to get to the missing informations? thanks a lot!

Comment: you should show all relevant parts of the dsl and also what is not working.

Comment: i dont see a definitionen in your model. why do you import import  noreia_Rezepteditor.definitionen; and not noreia_Rezepteditor.* ?

Comment: (import happen on model level, not on metamodel level)

Comment: "definitionen" is simply the name of the file I want to import. Isnt it possible to simply call the file whose content I want to import?

Comment: maybe importURI scoping is what you are looking for, not importedNamespace

Comment: I am again sitting on the problem, changed to importURI and used whats done here(without the transitive part): [link](https://blogs.itemis.com/en/in-five-minutes-to-transitive-imports-within-a-dsl-with-xtext). It should  work the same in my project but its not sadly.  What I do not get is the folowing: When and where is the import of the information (so the inclusion of the data to the Ecore right?) actually happening? Normally I would get my scope by somehow searching the tree (starting with EcoreUtil.getRootContainer and so on) but the data of the imported file seems to simply not be there.

Comment: your scopeprovider will call into a scopeprovider delegate which will call into global scope provider. the global scope provider will query/filter the xtext index.

Comment: After a look at the "Implementing dsl with xtext" book I  entirely renewed the question, could you maybe have again a look? The book suggests that using the default global scope provider, even without explicit imports, refering to definitions defined in other files should work, so they should be on the same resource i guess. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: did should work ootb with no changes to scoping at all

Comment: thank you very much, now I found the source of error, bc I did change scoping: The customized "getScope" Method in the ScopeProvider, where now just SOME of the customizations (which look like `if(context instanceof SomeDefinition) {
   final EObject rootContainer = EcoreUtil.getRootContainer(context);
   List<SomeDefinition> candidates = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootContainer, SomeDefinition.class);
   return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);` are working. Any idea why its leading to some new "Couldnt resolve reference to..."-errors  and not behaving exactly like it would in one file?

Comment: cause rootContainer is the root of the file and your code collects within the file only.

Comment: yes, thank you thats the source of error, how can I access the information from the other files?

Comment: you dont. default scoping will do. (out of the box)

Comment: Thank you I found a way now. When using several files I figured that not ALL information is transported to my code generator (`for (e : resource.allContents. toIterable.filter (RecipeDefinition)){    
    e.doStuff;
   }` Some deep buried Properties (from cross-references) which I would need get lost which is not the case when just using one file. I guess the solution is some custom scoping?

Comment: Ok its even stranger, when starting the runtime it would transport all info, but from the second time on (so when triggering the generator via saving the editor) not all info is transported

Comment: i still cant follow what you are doing.

Comment: I edited the question again, now its executable and should be clear. Thanks for the great help!

Comment: the code is incomplete and not simplified. so i cannot try. i recomment you to debug linking at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.impl.DefaultLinkingService.getLinkedObjects(EObject, EReference, INode) please also note. debugger knows nothing about lazy linking so how do you test the null thing.
you should also get errors in editor then. do you?

Comment: I am sorry, there was a semicolon too much in the grammar. new xtext project with simply adding grammar getscope and dogenerate and then adding the two files in the runtime and adding a breakpoint at dogenerate(e.class) you can traverse down the tree(e->recipeSteps->calledSubrecipe->reciepSteps->service->name ) where you then see that this property is null instead of the actual name. Unfortunately I cannot debug the Plugin Dependency classes...

Comment: setting breakpoint wont trigger proxy  resolution.

Comment: => i need complete minimal reproducer

Comment: Since even in case I solve the null problem, I still would have the problem that my grammar demands customized scoping(what is also a problem since "rootnode" does not work for multiple files). I think I will leave it and simply changing grammar to make codefolding possible to just "fold the definitions away". After all its simply a usability thing. Thank you very much for your time!!